# Prevent Dynamics CRM 2011 from using last used form

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

By default dynamics saves the last form used by a user for a certain entity. If the user later opens an entity of the same type dynamics uses the last used form.

Is there a way to force dynamics to always use a certain form?

Comment: That's stored in the user settings, don't have code at hand right now, will look it up

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to this MVP's blog](http://gonzaloruizcrm.blogspot.it/2014/11/avoiding-form-reload-when-switching-crm.html) you can update `UserEntityUISettings` record for the specific owner and entity in a `Post-Retrieve` plugin to set the form to show.

You'll have to fetch and update the `UserEntityUISettings` which respects the following conditions:

- `ownerid` equals plugin context's `UserId`
- 'objecttypecode' equals the entity's type code (the number, not the string)

You need to update the `lastviewedformxml` attribute to set the form you want users to see. The attribute is a `string` which should have this format:

```
"<MRUForm><Form Type=\"Main\" Id=\"FORM_GUID_HERE\" /></MRUForm>"
```

Form GUIDs can be grabbed from any exported solution's `customization.xml` which includes the entity.

There are some gotchas to be aware of:

- This plugin is sandbox-able (so it's ok) but it's interacting with an undocumented attribute so make sure it works after any update (it should, but you never know...)
- "Special" users like SYSTEM don't have any record in `UserEntityUISettings` so if the query returns 0 records you shouldn't `throw`.
- I suspect that users would no longer be able to switch forms manually...
- This being a plugin on retrieve, it might slow down lookups

Comment: A custom plugin seems to be the only solution. Hoped for an option to deactivate this behavior. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You need to Write JavaScript to Switch form to default (or any other) form on load.

```js
function switchForm() {

// Get current form's Label
var item = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.getCurrentItem();
itemLabel = item.getLabel();

if (itemLabel != "Information")
{
  //load Information form
  var items = Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector.items.get();
  for (var i in items)
  {
    var form= items[i];
    var formId = form.getId();
    var formLabel = form.getLabel();

    //Check condition either on ID or Label from Form
    if (formLabel == "Information")
    {     
      form.navigate();
    } 
  }
}
```

Please check these:

[Xrm.Page.ui.formSelector item (client-side reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309560.aspx)

Comment: This wouldn't avoid the "wrong" form showing up (briefly, yes, but ...). Plus, the record would load twice.

Comment: @Alex yes you are right, form will load twice. I am not aware about any other way to check/update user settings.

Comment: As Alex said, unfortunately no option, because of the double load problem.

Comment: @Geaz I am also interested to see how it will be done without loading the form twice.